# What are oraxdb attributes in XSD?

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

In my project XML validation is failing.   Below is the XSD for that particular element. I tried my best to understand this but unable to get any fruitful result.

```
<xs:element name="xxxx" 
    type="xs:decimal" --Specifies either the name of a built-in data type
    oraxdb:propNumber="9698" 
    oraxdb:global="false" 
    oraxdb:SQLName="xxxx" 
    oraxdb:SQLType="NUMBER"
    oraxdb:memType="2" 
    oraxdb:MemInline="true" 
    oraxdb:SQLInline="true" 
    oraxdb:JavaInline="true"/>
```

Could you please let me know what the meaning of all these attribute like `oraxdb:propnumber = "9698"?

Comment: Have you defined the `oraxdb` namespace prefix somewhere? I also assume that the *--Specifies either the name of a built-in data type* is not actually there because it is not legal here. Do you have an error message to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Meaning of `oraxdb` attributes

Assuming the `oraxdb` namespace prefix has been properly declared, typically on `xs:schema`,

```
xmlns:oraxdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb"
```

the extra attributes are Oracle-specific XML Schema annotations for customizing Java program elements to XML Schema mapping.

### Source of validation failing

Adding attributes from another namespace to XSD elements is fine; your validation problem must lie elsewhere.

If your real XSD actually has this line:

```
type="xs:decimal" --Specifies either the name of a built-in data type
```

that would be a syntax error because

```
--Specifies either the name of a built-in data type
```

is not allowed there.  Remove it.

Beyond that possibility, you'll have to show more of your XSD and possibly your XML for us to assess further.